# VBA with SQL queries

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I work in a FMCG company, I work in data department almost with reports
so on a daily basis, I have to refresh a SQL query to get the updated data of yesterday's sales and transactions on excel environment.

Now I have an idea, why do I not design a report that can be automatically updated from SQL?

I mean what do I now is that I run the SQL query to get data and then from this row data I get useful info. By inserting data into pivot tables then linking my reports to this data via Vlookup for example.

So is there any VBA code that I can put in the report workbook that goes to SQL Server or even the SQL file and run the query then refreshes pivots and updates finally my report data, all this also I need it to be done on the background ?!

Example:

I have an Excel workbook report which is a table. That table is linked to another Excel workbook by Vlookup which is the SQL query powerpivot.

I need code that can auto-refresh the SQL query pivot automatically in the background once I open the report's workbook and then get the updated data into the the report table and refresh any pivot in the same report workbook

Comment: Powerquery is one option and excel has other inbuilt connection capabilities that will do this. No need for vba but yes you can also do with vba and recordsets. Google some ideas.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-microsoft-query-to-retrieve-external-data-42a2ea18-44d9-40b3-9c38-4c62f252da2e

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Get_data_from_db()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'set connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn_text = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=[password];Persist Security Info=True;User ID=[user];Initial Catalog=[dbname];Data Source=[ip/address]"
cn.Open (cn_text)
cn.CommandTimeout = 1000

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

'parameters
param = Cells(2, 1).Value

'call query, sp or simple select
With rs
    .ActiveConnection = cn

    QueryString = "exec your_sp '" + param + "'"
    .Open QueryString
    Range("A5").CopyFromRecordset rs
End With

Set rs = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image]

[Automatically run a macro when opening a workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/automatically-run-a-macro-when-opening-a-workbook-1e55959b-e077-4c88-a696-c3017600db44)

Comment: Can you please tell me what exactly i need to change in this code to implement on my env. , Note : I do not understand many in coding ....Thanks

Comment: you need to change `cn_text` (put your connection values instead of brackets) and `QueryString` - put your query